# How to await an auth object with hooks? (MongoDB Stitch in React Native)

Tags: mongodb, react-native, react-hooks, mongodb-stitch

I am using React Native to build an app that relies on MongoDB Stitch for authentication. More often than not, the app crashes because the **client** object has not yet loaded when I use it in the following line of code. The error I get is the infamous *TypeError: undefined is not an object* followed by *evaluating 'client.auth.user'*.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Stitch } from 'mongodb-stitch-react-native-sdk';

const APP_ID = '<my app ID>';

const client = Stitch.hasAppClient(APP_ID)
    ? Stitch.getAppClient(APP_ID)
    : Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient(APP_ID);

const { user } = client.auth;

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.home}>
            <Text>HOME</Text>
            <Text>Hi {user.profile.data.email}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Home;

const styles = {
    home: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
};
```

The example provided with the MongoDB Stitch NPM package uses *componentDidMount* (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-stitch-react-native-sdk#getting-started)), but I am trying to make this work using Hooks. I have tried *useEffect*, a bunch of *if* statements, *async/await*, placing the object in state with *useState*; No luck.

Comment: Can I see the mongoDB example ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sure, here's the sample code provided with the package (using componentDidMount): https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-stitch-react-native-sdk#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, you can use useEffect hook to instantiate the client and get the user info.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    _loadClient();
   }, []);

const [client,setClient] = useState({});
const [user,setUser] = useState({});

_loadClient() {
Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('<your-client-app-id>').then(client => {
 setClient(client);

  if(client.auth.isLoggedIn) {
    setUser( client.auth.user)
  }
});
```

}

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried using this code, and it works by itself, but as soon as I attempt to use the client from state (i.e. const { user } = client.auth) I still get the usual error. I think useEffect allows an initial render to happen before executing its function (_loadClient() in this case), and that causes the error. I wish I could have the entire component wait until _loadClient is done before doing anything else.

Comment: You should be able to check if the client is loaded and render something else instead. 
Like, `<Text>Hi, {user ? user.profile.data.email : 'stranger' </Text>`. Maybe even use the `?.`-conditional access operator.

And I guess this is what the new experimental react suspense thing is all about? https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html